# How to display Get-Help info outside console

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script in which I need to take the Get-Help info for a file and display to the user in a modal window. It displays so nicely when I run the command from the console:

```
NAME
    Format-Table

SYNOPSIS
    Formats the output as a table.


SYNTAX
    Format-Table [[-Property] <Object[]>] [-AutoSize] [-DisplayError] [-Expand {CoreOnly | EnumOnly | Both}] [-Force] [-GroupBy <Object>] [-HideTableHeaders] [-InputObject <PSObject>] [-ShowError] [-View <String>] [-Wrap] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    The Format-Table cmdlet formats the output of a command as a table with the selected properties of the object in each column. The object type determines the default layout and properties that are displayed in each column, but you can use the Property 
    parameter to select the properties that you want to see.

    You can also use a hash table to add calculated properties to an object before displaying it and to specify the column headings in the table. To add a calculated property, use the Property or GroupBy parameter.


RELATED LINKS
    Online Version: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821775
    Format-Custom 
    Format-Hex 
    Format-List 
    Format-Wide 

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Format-Table -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Format-Table -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Format-Table -full".
    For online help, type: "get-help Format-Table -online"
```

but piping it straight to an outside window will look something like this:

```
@{examples=@{example=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}; inputTypes=@{inputType=@{type=@{name=System.Management.Automation.PSObject}; description=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}}; alertSet=@{alert=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}; syntax=@{syntaxItem=@{name=Format-Table; parameter=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}}; parameters=@{parameter=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}; details=@{description=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]; verb=Format; noun=Table; name=Format-Table}; description=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]; relatedLinks=@{navigationLink=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}; returnValues=@{returnValue=@{type=@{name=Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format}; description=System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]}}; xmlns:maml=http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/2004/10; xmlns:command=http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/command/2004/10; xmlns:dev=http://schemas.microsoft.com/maml/dev/2004/10; xmlns:MSHelp=http://msdn.microsoft.com/mshelp; Name=Format-Table; Category=Cmdlet; Synopsis=Formats the output as a table.; Component=; Role=; Functionality=; PSSnapIn=; ModuleName=Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility}
```

I realize this is because it's not actually a string, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse the returned MamlCommandHelpInfo to nicely display outside the console. For some elements of the Get-Info return object I can do something like this to pick out individual sections (though even the output of this needs more formatting):

```
$helpText = Get-Help Format-Table | select synopsis
```

But for something like the parameters section, I keep hitting this PSObject[], and looping through I can't get any info out of individual objects (which I assume hold the array of parameters).

There's gotta be a better way to do this... any ideas/tricks? Thanks!

Comment: `$helpText = Get-Help Format-Table | Out-String`

Comment: omg. you are a blessing. Clearly I'm a newb to PS :) thanks a bunch!